# Grub opens when trying to install Ubuntu with live USB (after deleting linux partition)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I had ElementaryOS installed alongside Windows 10, it had some issues so I deleted the eOS partition from Windows. After I did that, instead of Grub options, the Grub2 console would open (it doesn't say grub rescue, just grub).

If from the BIOS I choose Ubuntu (from USB), then the Grub console appears, if I choose Windows 10, it boots up properly.

When I do `ls` I get the following:
`(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1, glt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)`

When I do `ls` for each partition I get `Filesystem is unknown` for all of them except (hd1,gpt2) for which it says `Filesystem is fat`. It says possible files are: `efi/` `System Volume Information/`.

The `(hd1,gpt)/efi` contains `Microsoft/` `Boot/` and `ubuntu`. In `...efi/Boot` there are 2 files: `fbx64.efi` and `bootx64.efi`. In `...efi/ubuntu` there are `fw/` `fwupx64.efi` `grubx64.efi` `shimx64.efi` `mmx64.efi` `bootx64.efi` `grub.cfg`

When i type Boot it says `you need to load the kernel first`.

I'm afraid I have deleted some grub files or smth when I deleted the partitions, but I am not sure. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will install its own Grub. Your currently installed Grub doesn't know anything about the Live (USB)CD. So insert your USB-Stick, choose in your bios to start from it (like  external drive) and Ubuntu's installation process will take care of it. Removing a Linux distro will not remove your Grub.

Comment: When I select the USB it doesn't boot Ubuntu, Grub console opens instead. Most fixes I've seen require booting Ubuntu from the live USB and I can't do that for some reason...

Comment: If you insert the usb stick and you select the correct "disk" in bios, your hardware will boot into the usb stick. If Grub opens, you did not configure your hardware to boot from stick. You could even disable the other "drives" as last resort (only to reactivate on next boot)